# Exception while import from excel using openXML

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I would like to deserialize all the data from the excel file to list.

I am using this code

```
class ExcelImport
{
    Workbook workBook;
    SharedStringTable sharedStrings;
    IEnumerable<Sheet> workSheets;
    WorksheetPart custSheet;
    WorksheetPart orderSheet;
    string FilePath;
    ExcelStorage provider;
    Stiker[] ans;
    List<Stiker> StikerList;

    public ExcelImport(string fp)
    {
        FilePath = fp;


    }




    public List<Stiker> dothejob()
    {
        using (SpreadsheetDocument document =
    SpreadsheetDocument.Open(FilePath, true))
        {
            StikerList= new List<Stiker>();
            workBook = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook;
            workSheets = workBook.Descendants<Sheet>();
            sharedStrings = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
            StikerList = Stiker.LoadStiker(custSheet.Worksheet, sharedStrings);
            return StikerList;
        }
    }
```

But from some reson I get exception in the line:`sharedStrings =
          document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;`

that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".

After the above saggestion found that the

```
if (sharedStringTablePart == null)
{
// report a problem
}
```

rerurn null

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the properties in the source line will be "null" and have no value.

You'll want to either use a debugger to figure this out (set a breakpoint on the line and hover the mouse over each property), or break down the line into separate statements. Something like:

```
var workBookPart = document.WorkbookPart;

if (workBookPart == null)
{
    // do something to report a problem
}

var sharedStringTablePart = workBookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
if (sharedStringTablePart == null)
{
    // report a problem
}

sharedStrings = sharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
```

This way your code can determine at run-time if there's an issue: this kind of "defensive" idea is usually a good idea when working with data created by some system other than your own.

Comment: the stange thing is that for one file its work and fro the other no

Comment: So it sounds like the two files have a different structure. See my updated answer for ideas on how to figure this out.

Comment: hi the `ar sharedStringTablePart = workBookPart.SharedStringTablePart;` return null any idea why it happened? and why it happend only in some file?

Comment: the same thing in some excel files, others are ok. What SharedStringTable is pesponsible for?

Answer (score 1):

After half a day parsing 2007, 2010, 2013 and convert some 2003->2007 and parsing them I got one method of parsing excel emitting SharedStringTable in some cases

```
 var link = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart;
           Func<Cell, string> selector = (cell) => cell.InnerText;

          if (link != null)
           {
               SharedStringTable sharedStringTable = document.WorkbookPart.SharedStringTablePart.SharedStringTable;
               selector = (cell) => cell.DataType == null ? cell.InnerText : cell.DataType == CellValues.SharedString ? sharedStringTable.ElementAt(Int32.Parse(cell.InnerText)).InnerText : cell.InnerText;

          }

         var values = wsPart.Worksheet.Descendants<Cell>().Select(cell =>selector(cell) ).ToArray();
```

Comment: This works with either xlsx files (even converted from 2003) :) I hope to help ones like me killed by ms excel versionism